# What is the meaning of 咬人猫

Tags: translation, meaning

I was looking up the meaning of `咬人猫` on google translate. `咬人猫` translated to

```
Bite the cat
```

I know a little bit of kanji and know that `人` means `person/human/man ...` and `猫` means cat. So "Bite the cat" surprised me as there is nothing related to "person/human ... ".

Unconvinced, I tried `咬猫` which also translated to

```
Bite the cat
```

Now I realised Google is just messing me with, LOL. Anyway, jokes aside, I tried the `人猫` next, which translated to

```
Human cat
```

This made more sense to me.

Looking up further, I got the following

```
咬 yǎo
    （指用牙）bite

   被狗/蛇咬了一口
     get bitten by a dog/snake
```

So after all this, I was pretty sure it is thing related to "bite" and "human cat". So, I believe `咬人猫` should be something like

```
biting human cat
```

**So what is the actual meaning?**

**PS**: No idea of Chinese language and sub-par knowledge of kanji. Was just curious, so ended up here :)

Comment: 咬人猫 means 'cat that bite human'. XD. No 咬猫 or 人猫. But there is 猫人 for human cat.

Comment: Human-biting cat. 咬人 means (v.) to bite human or (adj.) human-biting.

Comment: @NS.X.  So it's the other way around. Thanks. In that case, what will biting human-cat be? And by human-cat, I mean something like a cat-man, if that makes any sense. Will it be like `咬猫人`?

Answer (score 3):

Well, in Taiwan, "咬人猫" is the local name of  [urtica thunbergiana (蕁麻)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urtica_thunbergiana).

It's a poisonous plant.

[image]
[image]

The moral is: don't rely on google translate solely :)

Comment: So how is the local name pronounced?

Answer (score 2):

You're enough to make jokes... 咬人猫 just a nikename of an account of famous website.She's a cute girl,and made some videos.[image]

Comment: looks like this is not a simple language question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, an Australian women I know, here in China, took in a cat from the streets, because she felt sorry for it. It turned out to be a 咬人猫，it bit her arm badly and she had to pay 2000 RMB for an anti-rabies injection!

In English, we use relative clauses a lot for description:

```
That is the cat [that bites people]. [relative clause]
```

Chinese mostly puts this kind of description in front of the noun, so we get:

```
That is a [bites people] cat   
那是只[咬人的]猫。
```

A person who bites cats (probably not many of them！) would be

```
一个咬猫的人
```

Batman is 蝙蝠侠 which is 'bat knight/hero'
Superman is 超人 which is 'surpass person'

If a hypothetical Catman were a hero, you could maybe call him '猫侠‘, but if he was evil than possibly '恶猫人’ and if this villain bites people, that could be expressed as thus:

```
  恶猫人再次咬了一个人
  Catman has bitten someone again
```

Did I just hear a bloodcurdling 'Meow'? Oh no, it's Catm ..... arrrgh!